# Spark, HIVE; System design question handing 2TB per day

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, pyspark, bigdata

My team needs to build a `HIVE` database to process and access very large amount of data. The data is `json` format, so we like to squeeze data into a table format (like csv table) to remove redundancy, and want to do some post-processing to make the data easy to access/process later on. We have limited experience building such large systems, so I like to know a number of different options to consider before we start building the system.

**Assumptions**:

- System configuration: 25 nodes cluster, each node has 20 CPUs and 20TB storage.
- `HDFS`, `Spark`, `HIVE` installed.
- Data feed: Each day 2,000 files, each file (`json.gz`) is gziped 1GB (1M records), so daily data volume is 2TB.
- Data format: json format. {`userID`:val1, `timestamp`:val2; `key1`;val3, `key2`:val4...} the number of users(total) is 10M, and the number of keys are 1,000.
- Desired parsed output data is `csv` tabular format (I assume this is the most convenient way for post-processing and `HIVE`): The data is mixed with 10 different types, therefore, it is desirable to split the data into 10 independent tables (`csv`) with different number of columns:

  1. Table A: column 10
  2. Table B: column 20
  3. Table C: column 6
  4. Table D: columns 30
     …
  5. Table J:  columns 14
- The `csv` data needs some post processing: Each Table will contain records of 10M users, and each user have 100 records with timestamps: We need to sort the table by `UserID` and `timestamp`; then compute some values for each `userID`. (ex. apply a diff function to column A1 and remove negative values).
- Post processed output volume per day is 500MB uncompressed csv as it removes significant overheads from `json` keys and redundant data. Then will raw `json` files will be removed from local `HDFS`.

**System design.**: This is my current system design

1. Store data: unzip `gz.json` files and store `json` files into `hdfs` folder `"/day1"`.
2. `json` parsing: use `pyspark` to parse each `json` file into `csv` format and store them into `hdfs` folder `"/proc_0/day1/"`.

   Process each file and record,  split them into 10 different files according to the data type (different tables).

   The total number of output files/day: 2,000*10 = 20,000 files.

   (ref: https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/spark-sql-json-examples-python-using-world-cup-player-data/)

   `df =sqlContext.read.json('test.json')`
3. Postprocessing: use `pyspark` and for each table, apply sorting to the table and apply process each column, then store the output `csv` files to hdfs "/proc/day1".
4. Hive: To access the data, use the `csv` files in `"/proc/"`.
5. (Optional process): Store `csv` files into `ORC` table and remove the original `json` and temporal `csv` files. This will further reduce the output data volume.

Comment: Is Hive a requirement? You could use Spark Thrift Server as your query engine, which supports Hive drivers

Comment: `HIVE` is not a requirement, but I though that is the easiest way to handle the large volume of data for data analysis. I will check how `Spark` `Thrift` works.

Comment: You'll still want a Hive metastore  to persistently store a schema for your raw data, rather than hold it all in a DataFrame in memory for Spark, but Hive would need tuned to use Tez for it to be faster than Spark. Also, Presto is another faster option. All of the above work best with Parquet or ORC rather than CSV or JSON, though. Then, if it's possible to get data in bz2 format rather than gz, that's a splittable archive format, which hadoop/spark prefer

Comment: Overall, though, you're going to need much more storage if you get 10% per node of your total capacity in raw format, daily. In the end, you'll probably start having storage problems after about a few months... In order to process gz data, it needs to be decompressed, which takes more storage until you store it in some columnar format **and** delete the old, raw data

Comment: It's not clear where the files come from, but if you could send JSON messages one at a time (via Kafka, Nifi, etc) rather than 20x 1M record files, then you can actually pre-aggregrate and process data as it arrives in smaller time windows than a day (maybe hourly). Then Kafka Connect or Nifi or Spark Streaming could load a partitioned Hive table for you

Comment: I will check if `bz2` format is available from the source, which would reduce the overhead from the `unzip` process. I think directly feeding uncompressed `json` may induce too much delay due to the network bandwidth from the data source.

Comment: @cricket_007  KUDU, would you consider that instead of Parquet? I suspect the 2TB per day precludss this. Your thoughts?

Comment: Parquet is a storage format. Kudu is a database that offers speeds between Hbase and Impala. They are complementary

Comment: I think I missed that the output `csv` will be significantly smaller than the  volume of original raw data. My rough estimation is around 500MB uncompressed `csv` per day.

Comment: Maybe this is slightly off topic, but does it have to be a physical datacenter cluster? Going with the cloud (AWS) instead will be better, cheaper, and far more adaptable to change in the long run. Friends don't let friends build datacenters.

Comment: Because we are using the existing system, so we are not considering using AWG at this moment. But we will consider that next time. Thanks for your comment.